# If we point a laser beam from a fixed place to a very distant object will that point move in six months?

Tags: speed-of-light, astrophysics, earth

As I understand light does not translate itself in direction of its oscillation... So if Earth is moving the trajectory of a laser beam which is emitted from a fixed place should make a point on a very distant object which should oscillate during six months as Earth changes direction in orbit around the Sun and the laser beam needs a while to reach that distant point.Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It depends on whether you keep adjusting the pointing direction with time.